# How can you get the URL of a wall post in Facebook?

Tags: facebook

When you use the notification system to go to a post ("X friend commented on your post"), you are taken to a page with *just* that post, not your entire wall. You can also get there if you receive an email notification and click on see the message, but, **how can you get that URL for any given post, without the notification/email**?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Hover over the timestamp for the post.  It is a link very similar to the way it works on Twitter.

Comment: Wow that is the least intuitive way to ever do that... I didn't even knew it was a link I thought it was just a label! Plus hovering shows the timestamp... how are you suppose to figure that its a link to the post! Well good thing we got webapps :) Thanks @rchern

Comment: +1 Just a few days ago I used a screen capture because I didn't think this was possible!

Comment: Sadly, its another example of the trend of looking clean at the expense of intuitiveness, google does it, and the iphone has a lot of examples also (who would ever intuitive think to drag an app onto another app). The tech generation (of which I am a part) will play enough or search to find these things out, but the less tech savvy and older generations really suffer.

Answer (score 5):

Rebecca Chemoff is right..though you don't need to hover. Just click on the "date" of the post. For example, on every post, there is the date, like "9 November" -- that contains a link. Click the date, and voila, the url of the post appears.